# Problema ao apagar um arquivo

Tags: python-3.x, log

eu fiz um pequeno gerenciador de logs. é para algo simples, então como está serve. a cada dia eu quero apagar e gerar um novo, porem meu codigo está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo: 'teste.log'

```
def manage_log():
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(filename=f"teste.log", level=logging.INFO)

        arquivo = open("teste.log")
        arq = arquivo.read()
        arquivo.close()

        dia = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%d'))

        if f'[{dia}]' not in arq:
            logging.info(f" [{str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%d'))}] ")

        elif arq[11:14] != dia:
            os.remove("teste.log")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\033[1;31;mmanage_log error: {e}\033[;;m")
```

Answer (score -4):

Parece que o arquivo "teste.log" está sendo usado por outro processo quando você tenta abri-lo ou removê-lo. Isso pode acontecer se o arquivo estiver sendo usado por outro programa ou se você tiver aberto o arquivo manualmente e o deixado aberto enquanto o seu código está sendo executado.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode adicionar um bloco "finally" ao seu código para garantir que o arquivo seja fechado corretamente depois que o código terminar de usá-lo. Por exemplo:

```
def manage_log():
try:
    logging.basicConfig(filename=f"teste.log", level=logging.INFO)

    arquivo = open("teste.log")
    arq = arquivo.read()

    dia = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%d'))

    if f'[{dia}]' not in arq:
        logging.info(f" [{str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime('%d'))}] ")

    elif arq[11:14] != dia:
        os.remove("teste.log")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"\033[1;31;mmanage_log error: {e}\033[;;m")
finally:
    arquivo.close()
```

Isso garantirá que o arquivo seja fechado corretamente, independentemente do que acontecer no resto do código.

Comment: Ao perguntar e ao responder não cumprimente, não agradeça, não use slogans não use frases de efeito. Seja mais técnico e menos passional. Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Se quiser fazer uma comunicação mais pessoal use o campo de comentários(mas tenha em mente que o bot do site ou a moderação, alertada pela comunidade, pode o remover o comentário).